# Which elements does the Directed Acyclic Graph contain?

Tags: gradle, directed-acyclic-graphs

There is a picture of a DAG in the book 'Building and Testing with Gradle' which i don't understand and is not well explained.

The DAG picture contains nodes like 'projects', 'dependencies', 'clean', 'help', 'tasks' and 'properties' which are stand alone with no reference to other nodes.

1) I thought in a directed graph nodes must have references (edges). Is that wrong?

2) The other question is: Are these stand alone nodes e.g. 'properties' or 'help' part of the DAG?

Unfortunately i can't upload that image to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion that a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) *must* contain edges (arcs) is incorrect. A graph that consists entirely of [isolated vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29) is a perfectly valid DAG.

Now, whether the picture that you describe actually makes sense, I can't say without seeing the picture and the surrounding prose.

Comment: I know that tasks are nodes and edges are the 'dependsOn'. But what about 'dependencies', 'properties', 'projects'? In the mentioned picture these are also nodes. Is that correct? Are these nodes part of the DAG?

Comment: 'dependencies', 'properties', 'projects' are also tasks. In difference they have no dependencies to other tasks. They are also part of the DAG.